# functions that return promises must be async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, tslint

When I run tslint on my code I get the following error

```
functions that return promises must be async
```

Here is the code

```
private doSomething(): void {
    fetch(myUrl)
        .then((rsp: Response) => rsp.text()) // <-- gives error
        .then(txt => this.txt = txt);
}
```

Not sure now how to fix this because the code runs just fine! Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Kraylog no...that's not how fetch() API works. `rsp.text()` returns promise

Comment: `rsp` is the response from `Fetch`, so I don't think it can be synchronous

Comment: response.text() returns a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text;

Comment: Are you using the correct Response type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message is caused by the tslint rule [promise-function-async](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/promise-function-async/).

You can adhere to this rule by adding async on your arrow function expression:

`.then(async (rsp: Response) => rsp.text())`

Comment: If I do that I get the following error: `TSLint: Spaces before function parens are disallowed (space-before-function-paren)`

Comment: Remove the space inbetween async and the opening paren. You can also configure your editor/linter to autofix some of these errors.